# Running a Script to change a wp-config file DB Name

Tags: linux, database, wordpress, bash

I teach students how to fix wordpress sites and I would like to write a script that looks at what information they have in their wp-config.php and add a single letter or number to the database name.

For example the line is such

```
define('DB_NAME', 'cpanelUser_NameofDB');
```

I would like to add a number or a line to the end of `NameofDB`

I can use this to isolate the cpanelUser_NameofDB

```
grep -i 'DB_NAME' wp-config.php | cut -d"'" -f4
```

but I'm not sure how to add information, nor if this is the correct script I should run to get there. I would also like it to not matter what the name of the database is since it will be ran on multiple sites. I'm sure I could use regex but I'm not too versed in that and would not know where to start. Help please!

Comment: Did you think about the possibiltity, that the `define` statement might span several lines, including arbitrary comments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) on the server:

Go to the website root:

```
cd /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs
```

...and list all the wp-config values:

```
wp config list
```

[image: wp config list - result example]

...or set the value you need to change:

```
sudo wp config set DB_NAME put_my_custom_db_name_here --allow-root
```

See more WP CONFIG features here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed for this purpose to fix this line:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

id=34

sed -i "s/^.*DB_NAME.*$/define('DB_NAME', 'cpanelUser_NameofDB${id}');/" wp-config.php
```

flag **-i** means that we do change in file directly.

Alternatively you can make template file and generate new file while sed works on stdin and stdout

```sh
#!/bin/bash

id=34

cat wp-config.php-template| sed "s/^.*DB_NAME.*$/define('DB_NAME', 'cpanelUser_NameofDB${id}');/" > wp-config.php.$id
```